# vim and snipmate / snippets: how to create custom behavior

Tags: vim, code-snippets, snipmate

Here's my snippet:

```
# Get repository of a table:
snippet repo
    $$2 = $this->getRepository('${1:Bundle}:${2:TableName}')
    ${3}
```

When I use it, here's what it may generate:

```
$Person = $this->getRepository('MyBundle:Person')
$Address = $this->getRepository('MyBundle:Address')
```

I would like the first one to be lowercase, always lowercase, and give me something like:

```
$person = $this->getRepository('MyBundle:Person')
$address = $this->getRepository('MyBundle:Address')
...
```

. Is there a way to do this with the snipmate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done with *snipMate*. I've tried to implement this, but (especially when the transformation changes the number of characters), it's impossibly hard with the current implementation.

That may be the best reason to move to [the UltiSnips plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715), a modern, maintained alternative (that however requires Python support). There, the feature is called *transformation*, and uses a `${<tab stop no/regular expression/replacement/options}` syntax. You can use the `\L` regular expression atom to lowercase the replacement.

Comment: I was looking for recursive snippets (snippet in snippet) as well. Many thanks for this information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible with snipmate but you may have a look at UltiSnips. UltiSnips uses a very similar template syntax (very easy to convert) and is much more versatile.
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715